# How to configure JBoss AS7.1.1 to reference a CORBA Remote-Bean

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, glassfish, ejb, corba

I'm switching for local development from Glassfish to JBoss. I'm not very experienced with CORBA and Remote-Beans. How can I configure the following GF-Configuration in JBoss AS 7.1.1?

The config from GF:

```
<external-jndi-resource res-type="javax.naming.Reference" description="" jndi-name="ejb/DocumentServiceInvocation" factory-class="com.sun.jndi.cosnaming.CNCtxFactory" jndi-lookup-name="ejb/DocumentServiceInvocation">
  <property name="java.naming.provider.url" value="corbaname::server01:9812,:server01:9813/NameServiceServerRoot"></property>
</external-jndi-resource>
```

and...

```
  <servers>
    <server name="server" config-ref="server-config">
      ...
      <resource-ref ref="ejb/DocumentServiceInvocation"></resource-ref>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

My web.xml:

```
<ejb-ref>
   <ejb-ref-name>ejb/DocumentServiceInvocation</ejb-ref-name>
   <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
   <home>mypackage.DocumentServiceInvocationHome</home>
   <remote>mypackage.DocumentServiceInvocationRemote</remote>
</ejb-ref>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to take a look at http://www.jacorb.org/. It is a tried and tested ORB bridge between Java and CORBA. It makes interaction between CORBA and Java as simple as web services. It can be used with JBoss.

Answer (score 1):

There is a test case in
jboss-eap-6.2-src/testsuite/integration/basic/src/test/java/org/jboss/as/test/integration/ejb/iiop/naming